# What topic in Theology does Tozer's "The Saint Must Walk Alone" fit under?

Tags: reference-request

### Context:

I recently read Tozer's "The Saint Must Walk Alone." I'm searching for similar material.

Now, it's clear that it does not fit under "pre-destination" or "trinity".

The closest thing I can think of "preservation of the saints" -- but even that is not quite right -- the focus seems to focus more on "solitude."

### Question:

- Is there some word, on the calibre of christology, eschatology, soteriology -- that describes the type of issues Tozer addresses?
- If not, what general "Christian Topic" does Tozer's "The Saint Must Walk Alone" fall under?

Comment: I've not read *The Saint Must Walk Alone*, but if you're looking for material on **discipleship**, I've heard that Bonhoeffer had some interesting, if sometimes controversial & not-entirely-orthodox things to say.

Comment: "When Christ calls a man, he bids him come and die." -- The Cost of Discipleship <-- is this the book you're referring to?

Comment: That's one. Haven't read it myself, but I've heard it's worth considering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tozer often preaches very insightfully about **sanctification** by discarding many superficial views that causes us to make Christianity fake and hypocritical.  A man who is truly vexed by the sin of the world, and truly despised by it, can't help but feel lonely.

Jesus was a man of sorrow:

> He was despised and rejected by mankind, a man of suffering, and familiar with pain. Like one from whom people hide their faces
>   he was despised, and we held him in low esteem. (NIV Isaiah 53:3)

Paul had sorrows from his faith:

> I speak the truth in Christ—I am not lying, my conscience confirms it through the Holy Spirit— 2 I have great sorrow and unceasing anguish in my heart. (NIV Romans 9:1-2)

Jesus said that those who enter into mourning for sin, theirs and the world's would be blessed (in a happy state)

> Blessed are those who mourn, for they will be comforted. (NIV Matthew 5:4)

These any many similar subjects about picking up our cross, counting the cost, suffering persecution, being lonely on account of it, mourning for sin, striving in prayer, etc. These can  probably all be classified under **sanctification and practical Christian practice or experience.**

Tozer almost exclusively preaches and writes on this subject.

Comment: This is interesting. Initially, I viewed this loneliness as a _proactive_ decision; but in your framework, it's an effect of sanctification.